# How to make a math summation in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I am a newbie with sqlite and studying online with sqlite tutorial. I made a board with 2 columns, one like 1 2 3 4 and one like 10 20 30 40.

I read online that I could make some math operations with sqlite, for example 10+20=30, or 20+30=40, but I can not make it in sqlite. I mean that if I want to make a math operation like this a(1) + a(4) , 1 and 4 are the position, and a is the value, how can I make it in sqlite board ? Could you please give me some ideas? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT sum(the_column_to_sum) AS mysummation FROM your_table;`

Will [**sum**](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc) all the rows, the result set will be a single row with a single column named mysummation. Obviosuly the_column_to_sum and your_table will be replaced with the respective names.

As regards to

> I mean that if I want to make a math operation like this a(1) + a(4) , 1 and 4 are the position, and a is the value,

There is no concept of potistion in regards to rows unless they are ordered using ORDER by.

However, if you mean that the row with a value of 1 in the first column (10 in the second column) should be added to the row with a value of 4 in the first column (40 in the second column) and that a is some other value then you could use :-

```
SELECT sum(the_column_to_sum) + your_value AS mysummation FROM your_table WHERE the_first_column IN(1,4);
```

or

```
SELECT sum(the_column_to_sum) + your_value AS mysummation FROM your_table WHERE the_first_column = 1 OR the_first_column = 4;
```

As an example :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (col1 INTEGER, col2 INTEGER);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(1,10),(2,20),(3,30),(4,40);
SELECT sum(col2) AS summation FROM mytable;
SELECT sum(col2) + 100 AS summation FROM mytable WHERE col1 IN (1,4);
SELECT sum(col2) + 100 AS summation FROM mytable WHERE col1 = 1 OR col1 = 4;
```

Produces 3 results as per :-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need `SUM()` and a `WHERE` clause.
So for this table:

```
| id  | col |
| --- | --- |
| 1   | 10  |
| 2   | 20  |
| 3   | 30  |
| 4   | 40  |
```

the query should be:

```
select sum(col) as result
from tablename
where id in (1, 4)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bNrR8qUUq4qAa4dUqQdXPV/0).
Results:

```
| result |
| ------ |
| 50     |
```

Answer (score 0):

When calculating totals in SQL the first thing that comes in mind are the aggregation functions `SUM` and `COUNT`.

Which is already covered by the other answers.

But I figured that it was worth mentioning that a self-join could also work for this case.
Although you won't often see it used this way.

**Sample data:**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE yourtable
> (
>   col1 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
>   col2 INTEGER NOT NULL
> );
>
> INSERT INTO yourtable 
> (col1, col2) VALUES
> (1, 10),
> (2, 20),
> (3, 30),
> (4, 40);
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> select 
> t1.col1 as col1_1,
> t2.col1 as col1_2,
> t1.col2 as col2_1,
> t2.col2 as col2_2,
> (t1.col2 + t2.col2) as result
> from yourtable as t1
> join yourtable as t2 
>   on t2.col1 > t1.col1
> where (
>     (t1.col1=1 and t2.col1 = 4)
>  or (t1.col1=2 and t2.col1 = 3)
> )
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> col1_1 | col1_2 | col2_1 | col2_2 | result
> :----- | :----- | :----- | :----- | :-----
> 1      | 4      | 10     | 40     | 50    
> 2      | 3      | 20     | 30     | 50
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=3d2604ddeee48e5a233d2377d6e6abe4)*